# Why does ShellExecute not work?

Tags: c++, shellexecute

```
#include "ShellAPI.h";
ShellExecute(Handle,NULL,"file.txt",NULL,NULL,SW_RESTORE);
```

Why does this code not work?

Here the error screen:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Maybe because you need to put your `ShellExecute()` invocation inside of `int main(void) { }`? There are also errors inside of `ShellAPI.h` but since you didn't paste the contents of that file we can't help you with it.

Comment: [Did you just ask this question under a different account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574239/why-shellexecute-doesnt-work)

Comment: I've tried that, same error.
I I thought that ShellAPI.h is standard.
Tell me what i need to give you and i'll give you that.

Comment: Why does someone put a minus ? This is a normal question!

Comment: @GuitarFan Perhaps you meant `#include <ShellAPI.h>`. You may also need to `#include <windows.h>` first.

Comment: cdhowie, thank you for your answer. It helps, but now 
error C2065: 'Handle' : undeclared identifier
I don't know the handle. Handle is for some specific window, but i just try to run txt file.
int main(void)
{
 ShellExecute(Handle,NULL,"file.txt",NULL,NULL,SW_RESTORE);
}

Comment: @GuitarFan You would do yourself a favor to [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). *"This value can be NULL if the operation is not associated with a window."*

Comment: From the confusion in the question, I would recommend that you learn C++ first, and then expand to `ShellExecute` later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several problems:

- You need to include `windows.h` before you can include `shellapi.h`.
- When including system headers you should use `<>` around the header instead of `""`.
- You should not have a semicolon `;` after your `#include` directive.
- Your `ShellExecute()` call needs to be in a function, probably `int main(void)`.
- `Handle` is not defined. You probably want `NULL` per the [`ShellExecute()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which you should have already read).

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShellAPI.h>

int main(void) {
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "file.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Big thank you, but still, i have another error with your code:
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Parents\Desktop\hide3\hide3\Debug\hide3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Do you know what is that mean?

Comment: Here is my function:
int main(void)
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"file.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_RESTORE);
 return 0;
}

Comment: The error means you originally created a "Win32 project" but you should have created a "Win32 console project".

Comment: Can not I just create a Win32 project?  Why then some people tell me to use main function? ShellExecude doesn't work in win32 project?

Comment: @GuitarFan "Win32 project" is for programs with a window. "Win32 console project" is for programs that will run on the console (in a command prompt). They both have access to the same general stuff (console programs can actually create windows!) but they have a different signature for the entry point.